# PHP checkbox with if statement issue

Tags: php

i have this checkbox input in my form

```
<input name='new' type='checkbox' value='0' />
```

the column new in my database is TINYINT 
based on the value of the checkbox , i want to display a div with a class if the value is 1 so i implement this code

```
if(isset($_POST[$URL['new']]) 
   && isset($_POST[$URL['new']]) == 1)
   {
    echo '<div class="premiere">Premiere</div>';
    }
```

everything seems working fine , there's no error,warnings and notices.but the div didnot display in the page . what is wrong with the code and how i can fix it? thanks

Comment: Why are you using `$URL['new']`?

Comment: the is the name i gave the array element like that i have it <?php foreach ($URLS as $URL).i can change it

Comment: `$_POST["new"] ` is enough

Comment: @ObedLorisson if you are using foreach, $URL is the key. It is not an array. so you cannot call it as  `$_POST[$URL['new']]` if you need more help let us know what you really going to do.

Comment: yeah true , it's the key, i change the syntax , still not displaying

Comment: just echo $URL and see. Did you get any output?

Comment: when i echo it,it works but when i put the if statement , doesn't work, seems like it something with the code

Comment: actually i was testing to see if the check box value change dynamically when i checked the box the initial value in the input still stay the same that why it doesn't show up

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( isset($_POST["new"]) && $_POST["new"] == 1 )
{
  echo '<div class="premiere">Premiere</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think, you have apply second condition to check value of "new" variable.

you should write condition like this

```
if(isset($_POST[$URL['new']]) && $_POST[$URL['new']] == 1){
}
else{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( isset($_POST["new"]) && $_POST["new"] == 1 )
{
  echo '<div class="premiere">Premiere</div>';
}
```

Make sure class "premiere" not hidden through css code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query to display div on checking the checkbox and on unchecking checkbox you can hide the div displayed.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#new").change(function(e){
     var addDiv = $("#new").val();
     if($("#new").attr('checked'))
      { 
       $("#form2").append("<div class="premiere">Premiere</div>");
      }
      else
      {
       $(".premiere").remove();
      }
     });
    });
```

HTML Code:

```
    <form method="post" id="form2">
    <input id="new" name='new' type='checkbox'/>
    </form>
```

Hoping that this post will be very much useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

The prob was , i was trying to access the key from an array in a foreach loops , so i just remove the $_POST from the key and reference like URL['new'] instead. and it works fine.

```
if(isset($URL['new']) 
   && isset($URL['new']) == 1)
      {
  echo '<div class="new">Premiere</div>';
   }
```